# Facing Issue with Prism Template package Installation in windows 11 and visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

When trying to install the Prism package in Visual Studio 2022 it gives me the following error:

> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - -------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - vsixinstaller.exe version:
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - 17.1.1035-preview2
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - -------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Command line parameters:
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\VKU\Downloads\PrismTemplatePack.vsix
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - -------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Microsoft VSIX Installer
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - -------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Skipping product Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools (408b62bd) since it does not support extensions
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Initializing Install...
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Extension Details...
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Identifier         : Prism.TemplatePack.138e3411-ac97-4c11-8016-c27a831cba2e
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Name               : Prism Template Pack
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Author             : Brian Lagunas
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Version            : 2.3.0
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Description        : Snippets, Items Templates, and Project Templates for use in Prism application development.
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Locale             : en-US
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   MoreInfoURL        : https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   InstalledByMSI     : False
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.7.2,)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   SignatureState     : Unsigned
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Supported Products :
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           Version : [16.0,17.0)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           ProductArchitecture : x86
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           Version : [16.0,17.0)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           ProductArchitecture : x86
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           Version : [16.0,17.0)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -           ProductArchitecture : x86
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   References         :
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Prerequisites      :
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       -------------------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Name         : C# and Visual Basic
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Version      : [16.0,)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       -------------------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Name         : Visual Studio core editor
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Version      : [16.0,)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       -------------------------------------------------------
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Name         : NuGet package manager
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -       Version      : [16.0,)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Signature Details...
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -   Extension is not signed.
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 -
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Searching for applicable products...
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Found installed product - Global Location
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Professional 2022 (3)
> 23-03-2022 13:34:52 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData) at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
> at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

Comment: This is not code related, but IDE related. That being said it is likely on topic despite the poor formatting (it makes it hard to read). A quick google search has led me to [this github issue](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Templates/issues/39) that is still open where they are aware of the problem and provide a workaround (maybe it could help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the issues of the Prism template pack github, the pack is not supporting VS2022, you can find some workaround in this post

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Templates/issues/39

Notable workaround :
Unzip the vsix , change the version in extension.vsixmanifest, zip it back to be able to install it. You will get the snippets, but the auto creation of the viewmodel won't work when creating a Prism Usercontrol/View you will have to do it manually.

Comment: Consider adding some information of the workaround to your answer, otherwise it could be flagged as "link only answer"